# Habilitar clique na ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Quando insiro um `ImageButton` no layout da minha `ListView`, não é mais possível clicar na `ListView`, ou seja, o clique é desabilitado. Existe alguma forma de habilitar o clique na `ListView` quando tiver um `ImageButton` inserido em seu layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente,

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

não funciona para `ImageButton`.

Eu encontrei a solução [aqui](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html). No layout do seu xml para esses itens adicione

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

no root da view.

Funciona perfeitamente para um `ListView` com `ImageButton`.